# How can i get this text from multiple line in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file (Myfile.txt), line by line, which is very long and centered as shown below

```
...","ItemPrice":17000.0,"MustPay":17000.0,"PaywithCash":17000.0,"etc...
...","ItemPrice":900.0,"MustPay":900.0,"PaywithCash":900.0,"etc...
...","ItemPrice":1400.0,"MustPay":1400.0,"PaywithCash":1400.0,"etc...
```

so I want to get the number after the word "PayWithCash":, for example the first line is the number 17000 and so on to the next line, and save it to a new text file "result.txt"

```
1700
900
1400
```

I have tried several codes, including as below

```
echo off 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type Myfile.txt^|find "PayWithCash:"') do (
  set "line=%%a"
  set "line=!line:*PayWithCash =!
  set /a "last=!line:~1!" 2>nul
)
echo %last% >> result.txt
```

And yes, I still can't get the desired result, can you help me?

I use google translate, I hope you understand

Comment: You haven't got an instance of `PayWithCash<SPACE>`, so `set "line=!line:*PayWithCash =!` is unlikely to do what it was intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Correct `PayWithCash` to the correct case in the data, `PaywithCash` or add the `/i` switch to `find` to make the match case-insensitive.

Remove the colon as suggested by @Compo.

Remove the <kbd>Space</kbd> after `PayWithCash` in the `set` statement as there is no such <kbd>Space</kbd> in the data.

Since the result in `line` will now begin `":` you need to use `line:~2`

Test code I used:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q64838297.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%filename1%"^|find /i "PayWithCash"') do (
  set "line=%%a"
  set "line=!line:*PayWithCash=!"
  set /a "last=!line:~2!" 2>nul

  echo !last!
)
)>"%outfile%"

TYPE "%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q64838297.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`

Result:

```
17000
900
1400
```

Comment: I tried, but only the last line number appears. can you write the whole code for me?